# Increase speed of HashSet

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I have a List of objects with unique identifier (id), fetched from a DB. For a particular scenario I have to remove duplicates. For that purpose, I am storing it in a `HashSet`. However, that process takes some time.

I wanted to know how this `HashSet` identifies duplicates. `toString` function has been overridden. Is there any other function or something that I should override to help speedup the `HashSet` function?

Will hash function overriding be of any help?

Comment: HashSet uses `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: select distinct (...)

Answer (score 2):

You should be overriding the `hashCode` and `equals` methods. Those are the methods used to locate a key in the `HashSet`/`HashMap`.

The `HashSet` identifies duplicates by first calculating the `hashCode` of the object it is searching for, and then iterating over all the objects in the `HashSet` that share this `hashCode` and comparing them to the searched object with `equals`, until a match is found.